# Conferir elementos de Listas dentro de outras listas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boas,

Tenho duas listas

```
lista1 = [0,1,2,3]
lista2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Como é que eu confirmo se todos os elementos da lista1 estão dentro da lista2 ?

Por exemplo :

```
lista1 = [0,1,2]
lista2 = [1,2,3,4]

lista3 = [0,1,2,3]
lista4 = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Todos os elementos da lista1 não estão dentro da lista2 mas todos os elementos da lista3 estão dentro da lista4!

Já tentei fazer isto simplesmente fazendo :

```
if lista1 in lista2 :
    print('todos dentro')
```

Mas não funciona !
Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: talvez este [material](http://excript.com/python/for-loop-python.html) possa te dar um ajuda

Comment: Você está querendo aplicar teoria de conjunto em listas, já pensou em utilizar [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set)? Assim daria para fazer `{0, 1, 2, 3} <= {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} == True`

Comment: Primeiro, precisamos definir um detalhe. A lista `[1, 1]` está na lista `[1, 2]`? Isto é, quando houverem elementos repetidos, deverão ser considerados o mesmo elemento ou distintos?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim, consideramos o mesmo elemento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if lista1 in lista2 :
    print('todos dentro')
```

O que você comparou aqui não é se uma lista contém todos os elementos da outra, mas sim se uma lista contém a outra. São coisas distintas.

1. `a = [1, 2]`, `b = [1, 2, 3]` (`a in b` => `False`)
2. `a = [1, 2]`, `b = [[1, 2], 3]` (`a in b` => `True`)

Na situação (1) a lista `b` contém todos os elementos de `a`; na situação (2) a lista `b` contém a lista `a`. Você precisa verificar a situação (1), mas verificou a situação (2).

O que você pode fazer para verificar é fazer um laço percorrendo os elementos da primeira lista e verificar um a um se estão também na segunda lista. Em Python, a maneira mais simples de fazer isso seria:

```
if all(i in b for i in a):
    print('Todos dentro')
```

Isto é, verifica se `i` está em `b` para todo `i` que pertence a `a`.

Ou, como comentado, você pode utilizar teorias de conjuntos. No Python, você pode criar um conjunto a partir de uma lista a partir da estrutura `set`:

```
a = set([1, 2])
b = set([1, 2, 3])
```

E assim utilizar o método `set.issubset` para verificar se um conjunto é sub-conjunto de outro:

```
if a.issubset(b):
    print('Todos dentro')
```

Ou pelo operador `<=`, que faz a mesma coisa:

```
if a <= b:
    print('Todos dentro')
```